# Error al cerrar Connection, Statement y ResultSet dentro de try-catch-finally en Java, no se puede resolver como variable

Tags: java, mysql

Todavía tengo problemas para cerrar correctamente mis conexiones, el error que tengo ahora es que las variables de Connection, Statement y ResultSet, dice que debo crearlas localmente, entonces qué debo hacer?.

Mi código:

```
    String showTableSQL = "SELECT * FROM llamadas";
    try {
        Connection conn = conexion.getConnection();
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(showTableSQL);

        while (rs.next()) {
            // Obtenemos el modelo del JTable
            model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();

            // Agregamos las filas al JTable
            model.addRow(new Object[]{
                            Integer.toString(rs.getInt(1)),
                            rs.getString(2),
                            rs.getString(3),
                            rs.getString(4),
                            rs.getString(5),
                            Integer.toString(rs.getInt(6)),
                            Double.toString(rs.getDouble(7))
                                });
                            }

    } catch (SQLException errorSQL) { errorSQL.printStackTrace(); }
        finally { // Cerramos las conexiones, en orden inverso a su apertura
            try { rs.close(); } catch (Exception errorRS) { errorRS.printStackTrace(); }
            try { st.close(); } catch (Exception errorST) { errorST.printStackTrace(); }
            try { conn.close(); } catch (Exception errorCONN) { errorCONN.printStackTrace(); }
        }
```

El error es en

> rs, st y conn: cannot be resolved, create local variable

Espero puedan ayudarme a solucionar esto, llevo 2 días intentándolo. Estoy aprendiendo MySQL aún.

Cualquier ayuda es apreciada.

Comment: ya intentaste hacer mejor todo eso en un solo try y catch? `try { //todo} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`

Comment: Te refieres a esto: finally { try { rs.close(); st.close(); conn.close(); } catch (Exception errorRS) { errorRS.printStackTrace(); }}, ? es correcto también?.

Comment: me refiero a que solo manejes un try y un catch para eso

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cerrar correctamente las instancias de `Connection`, `Statement`, `ResultSet` y manejar bien todos los errores que pueden resultar usando el patrón típico del `try-catch-finally` no es fácil. Y si lo logras, el código no es elegante.

Por ejemplo, aún cuando corrijas tu problema immediato de mover la definición de las variables afuera del `try`, el código aún tiene por lo menos un defecto de diseño.

Digamos que el código lo corriges de esta manera *(y de paso, leyendo los comentarios bajo la respuesta de @Dev Joel, hay que aclarar que sí es necesario inicializar las variables a algún valor como `null`. Sin eso, el compilador Java no puede garantizar que las variables tengan algún valor asignado cuando son usadas en el bloque `finally`, y por eso se queja. Y de hecho, este punto está ligado al defecto que voy a demostrar)*:

```
String showTableSQL = "SELECT * FROM llamadas";

// inicializar las variables sí es necesario aquí.
Connection conn = null;
Statement st = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

try {
    conn = conexion.getConnection(); // <-- ¿qué pasa si un error sucede aquí?
    st = conn.createStatement();
    rs = st.executeQuery(showTableSQL);

    // ...    
} catch (SQLException errorSQL) {
    errorSQL.printStackTrace();
}
finally { // Cerramos las conexiones, en orden inverso a su apertura
    try { rs.close(); } catch (Exception errorRS) { errorRS.printStackTrace(); }
    try { st.close(); } catch (Exception errorST) { errorST.printStackTrace(); }
    try { conn.close(); } catch (Exception errorCONN) { errorCONN.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

Ahora imaginemos que algún error sucede en este sentencia:

```
conn = conexion.getConnection();
```

Eso causa que `st` y `rs` queden con valores `null`, y ahora, cuando el bloque `finally` se ejecuta, tanto `rs.close();` como `st.close()` van a lanzar un `NullPointerException` que se pudiera haber evitado.

De modo que la forma correcta de manejar el bloque `finally` es verificando si las variables están a `null` antes de intentar cerrarlas:

```
finally { // Cerramos las conexiones, en orden inverso a su apertura
    try { if (rs != null) rs.close(); } catch (Exception errorRS) { errorRS.printStackTrace(); }
    try { if (st != null) st.close(); } catch (Exception errorST) { errorST.printStackTrace(); }
    try { if (conn != null) conn.close(); } catch (Exception errorCONN) { errorCONN.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

**Una mejor alternativa**

Lo anterior simplemente ilustra que es fácil cometer errores con este tipo de código debido a su complejidad. Y aún si logras hacerlo bien, la complejidad oscurece el verdadero propósito del código.

Por esta razón, a partir de Java 7, hay una mejor manera de manejar este tipo de situaciones, usando [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Usando esta técnica, nota cómo se puede simplificar tu código y cuán claro queda:

```
String showTableSQL = "SELECT * FROM llamadas";

try (Connection conn = conexion.getConnection();
     Statement st = conn.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(showTableSQL)) {

    // ...

} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Si lees la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), verás que esta estructura de código simplificada automáticamente maneja los aspectos siguientes:

- Todos los `.close()` se ejecutan automáticamente al final del bloque `try` y en el orden inverso a la apertura de las diferentes instancias.
- Si ocurre algún error con uno o más de los `.close()`, esas excepciones no reemplazan la excepción principal, si la hay.
- Relacionado al punto anterior, si ocurre más de un error, sea en el cuerpo del `try` o con los `.close()`, `e.printStackTrace()` incluye la información de todos los errores automáticamente.

Comment: +1 por  "try-with-resources". Java-7 ya cumplió 5 años, así debe programarse hoy

Comment: @leonbloy no solo eso, Java 7 incluso ya está depreciado, solo tiene mantenimiento a nivel comercial. Ahora se debe usar Java 8.

Comment: Increíble explicación, nadie lo hubiera podido hacer mejor. Muchísimas gracias, son todas esas cosas/trucos que es difícil encontrarlas en Google a la hora de aprender. Gracias por tomarte tu tiempo en escribir la respuesta y en tratar de ayudarme, te lo agradezco un montón!.

Answer (score 2):

El error es que estás declarando las variables `rs` `st` y `conn` dentro del bloque del primer `try{}catch(){}` y cuando intentas acceder en el `try{}catch(){}` del `finally` ya no son accesibles ya que están fuera del ámbito.

> El ámbito de una variable define su alcance de uso, o lo que es lo mismo, en que secciones de código una variable estará disponible. Fuera de este ámbito, una variable no podrá ser accedida (no existe).

**El ámbito de sus tres variables en su programa es el primer `try{} catch(){}`**.Para solucionarlo declara las variables a nivel de método (antes de  `try{}catch(){}`)

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String showTableSQL = "SELECT * FROM llamadas";
    ResultSet rs=null;
    Statement st=null;
    Connection conn = null;
try {
      conn = conexion.getConnection();
      st = conn.createStatement();
      rs = st.executeQuery("");
      /* Demás código */
    }
    finally {
try { if (rs != null) rs.close(); } catch (Exception errorRS) { errorRS.printStackTrace(); }
try { if (st != null) st.close(); } catch (Exception errorST) { errorST.printStackTrace(); }
try { if (conn != null) conn.close(); } catch (Exception errorCONN) { errorCONN.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

Comment: He intentado eso pero, luego me indica otro error en ST y RS: surround with try/catch. :( Screenshot: http://oi63.tinypic.com/21l4fgj.jpg

Comment: Verificar mi respuesta. que la **asignación** de las variables sea dentro del  try{}catch(){} no fuera. en la imagen declaras y asignas todo fuera. verificar mi respuesta por favor.

Comment: perfecto, me ha indicado que debo inicializar las tres variables, y le ha puesto "null" a las tres, no hay problema con eso?. Connection conn = null; - Statement st = null; - ResultSet rs = null;

Comment: @RobertGomez si te das cuenta en tu imagen y en la respuesta que te dieron, se esta inicializando dentro del try y en cambio tu lo estas haciendo fuera de eso

Comment: @MiguelOsorio lo sé pero, Eclipse me indica ese error y la forma de solucionarlo es hacerlos "null" antes del try/catch. Aveces estoy atado a lo que Eclipse desea, si no los hago "null", me marca el error y no me deja arrancar el programa :(

Answer (score -2):

Una forma seria que encierres todo en un try y catch mas o menos asi

**Conexion Singleton**

```
public class DBConnection {
private static DBConnection instance = null;
private Connection connection;
protected DBConnection(){
    this.conectaPGSQL();
}

public Connection getConnection(){
    return this.connection;
}

public static DBConnection getInstance(){
    if(instance == null){
        System.out.println("Instancia nueva");
        instance = new DBConnection();
    }
    return instance;
}

private Connection conectaPGSQL(){
    try{

            this.connection = //aqui va el condigo de tu driver manager para la conexion
            if (this.connection != null) {
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Falló al conectar la Base de datos","Connection Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            return this.connection;

    }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(),"Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
    }

}


}
```

**Ejemplo**

```
    String showTableSQL = "SELECT * FROM llamadas";
    DBConnection db = DBConnection.getInstance();
try {
    Connection conn = db.getConnection();
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(showTableSQL);

    while (rs.next()) {
        // Obtenemos el modelo del JTable
        model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();

        // Agregamos las filas al JTable
        model.addRow(new Object[]{
                        Integer.toString(rs.getInt(1)),
                        rs.getString(2),
                        rs.getString(3),
                        rs.getString(4),
                        rs.getString(5),
                        Integer.toString(rs.getInt(6)),
                        Double.toString(rs.getDouble(7))
                            });
                        }

                        rs.close();
                        st.close();
} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Comment: lo tenía antes así pero sigo recibiendo el error al ejecutar el programa de:  No operations allowed after connection closed, debido a esto alguien me recomendó usar finally con el try/catch para asegurar que se cierren pero, con una forma u la otra obtengo el mismo error, crees que tendrías unos minutos para ir a chat y puedas ayudarme?, soy nuevo en esto y llevo 2 dias tratando de resolverlo.

Comment: Lo interesante de tener una estructura como la que planteas. si se da una `Exception` antes de cerrar la conexión. está conexión quedará abierta. por eso se recomienda cerrar la conexión en el `finally` .

Comment: Aver ya te fijaste si no estas accediendo a otro metodo que ejecute una sentencia de sql, debido a que una vez que cierres conexion e intentes obtenes el getConnection() de nuevo este ya no te permitira, debido a que ya hay una conexion cerrada

Comment: @MiguelOsorio claro, antes solicito unos datos y los guardo en la base de datos, obviamente cierro las conexiones, luego despues, mas adelante, debo llenar el JTable con los datos guardados, entonces trato de hacer la conexion nuevamente con el codigo que hemos estado hablando. Entonces, este es el problema, ah... y qué puedo hacer?, dejar 1 conexion abierta siempre para todo el programa y cerrar la conexion al finalizar el programa?. Como te digo, es mi primera vez y apenas estoy entiendo como funciona esto.

Comment: ok si lo mas conveniente es que hagas una conexion mediante un singleton para hacer solo 1 unica instancia de conexion y usarla en tu aplicacion

Comment: @MiguelOsorio que es singleton?, llevo 2 semanas aprendiendo a interactuar con la base de datos, no soy experto todavía. En este tutorial: http://picarcodigo.blogspot.com/2013/05/jdbc-conexion-bases-de-datos-mysql.html, el autor solicita conexion y cierra cada vez que el desee, entonces, por qué a mí no me funciona. Estoy muy troncado en esto. Me gustaría entender lo que dices pero, no lo entiendo.

Comment: @RobertGomez es es porque data que hace una consulta abre la conexion de nuevo, cierra conexion y vuelve a abrir la conexion al usar ya que vuelve a instancia la clase

Comment: `conexion=new Conexion();` siempre que llama a eso vuelve a abrir la conexion es por eso que a el no le da error, debido a que carga d enuevo la conexion en su contructor

Comment: Recuerda que cada vez que cierra una conexion, y quieres hacer alguna consulta en la BD debes de volver a cargar la conexion

Comment: @MiguelOsorio si te fijas en mi código, yo hago lo mismo, la primera línea dentro del "try" es: conn = conexion.getConnection(); pero, por alguna razón, no me esta funcionando al parecer.

Comment: si hace el getConnection pero no haces la instancia de la clase de nuevo

Comment: haz esto antes del getConnection,,conexion=new ConexionBD();

Comment: @MiguelOsorio se me había pasado esa parte, muchas gracias hermano!, y por tu tiempo. ;)

Comment: deja modifico mi respuesta y le das aceptar vale?

Comment: Usar un singleton de conexión a base de datos es uno de los errores más comunes cuando se aprende a programar. Por favor evita comentar esta mala práctica. En proyectos reales esto no aplica.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza el que tu no sepas usar singleton en un proyecto real ese no es mi problema, y no es mala practica infórmate primero antes de comentar

Comment: Tengo más de 5 años de experiencia con Java. Créeme, esto es una muy mala práctica. Es más, puedo ponerte ejemplos donde malogro la aplicacion debido al uso de singleton para la conexión a la base de datos. Existen incontables ejemplos en internet de por qué esto es una muy mala idea. Y se nota que no has trabajado en proyectos reales o que trabajas en proyectos pequeños de un solo usuario.