# Null pointer access al usar una variable tipo String[] dentro de un try-catch

Tags: java

Error que recibo:

> Null pointer access: The variable listadoUsuarios can only be null at
>   this location

Variable tipo String[]:

```
String [] listadoUsuarios = null;
```

Código:

```
public void mostrarUsuariosExistentes() {
        sSQL =  "SELECT id_usuario FROM usuarios";

        String [] listadoUsuarios = null;
        int numFila = 0;
        PreparedStatement pstm = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            pstm = conn.prepareStatement(sSQL);

            rs = pstm.executeQuery(sSQL);

            while (rs.next()) {
                listadoUsuarios[numFila] = rs.getString("usuario");
                numFila++;
            }

        } catch (SQLException errorSQL) { errorSQL.printStackTrace(); }
        finally { // Cerramos las conexiones, en orden inverso a su apertura
        try { if (rs != null) rs.close(); } catch (Exception errorPSTM) { errorPSTM.printStackTrace(); }
        try { if (pstm != null) pstm.close(); } catch (Exception errorPSTM) { errorPSTM.printStackTrace(); }
        try { if (conn != null) conn.close(); } catch (Exception errorCONN) { errorCONN.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }
```

Lo que intento hacer es guardar todos los "usuarios" de inicio de sesión de mi tabla para mostrarlos en un JComboBox. Con esto poder seleccionar uno y luego mostrar todos sus datos en Textfield como su nombre, apellido, clave, etc..

El error lo recibo dentro del `while (rs.next())`.

Igualo `listadoUsuarios` como `null` pero, el error sigue ahí.

Alguna idea?, o es mejor usar ArrayList?.

Comment: Sugerencia: Mejor usa un `ArrayList`, actualmente la variable `listadoUsuarios` es `null`, por lo que nada va a funcionar al asignarle un valor, o bien, inicializa el array de String, en c# lo hacen así: `new string[20];` si no me equivoco, donde 20 es la cantidad máxima de elementos que necesitas en el Array.

Comment: lo igualé a null porque así el programa me lo pedía pero, sigue sin desaparecer el problema. No uso ArrayList porque no sé la cantidad de usuarios registrados que habrán en mi base de datos. Qué puedo usar para este caso?, solo deseo guardar todos los usuarios para mostrarlos en un JComboBox. @NaCl

Comment: Lee la respuesta de Luiggi :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No le has dado un valor útil a `listadoUsuarios`. Tu código, para el compilador, luce así:

```
String [] listadoUsuarios = null;
listadoUsuarios[0] = "algo";
//No tiene sentido
```

Lo mejor es usar un `List<String>` porque este puede crecer dinámicamente:

```
List<String> listadoUsuarios = new ArrayList<>();
//resto del código hasta la lectura de datos del ResultSet ...
while (rs.next()) {
    listadoUsuarios.add(rs.getString("usuario"));
}
```

Además, tu método pierde utilidad si es de tipo `void` y los datos obtenidos solo viven en el alcance del método. Sería mejor que el método devuelva la lista de usuarios obtenidos:

```
public List<String> obtenerUsuariosExistentes() {
    List<String> listadoUsuarios = new ArrayList<>();
    //código para llenar la lista con la consulta a base de datos...
    return listadoUsuarios;
}

//en otro método, en otra capa, muestras los usuarios
public void mostrarUsuariosExistentes() {
    List<String> listadoUsuarios = obtenerUsuariosExistentes();
    listadoUsuarios.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Adicional, recuerda tu pregunta [Error al cerrar Connection, Statement y ResultSet dentro de try-catch-finally en Java, no se puede resolver como variable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/36111/227) y lo que explica la respuesta aceptada. Aprovecha los beneficios de Java 7 y el `try-with-resources`:

```
public List<String> obtenerUsuariosExistentes() {
    List<String> listadoUsuarios = new ArrayList<>();
    try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sSQL);
         ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery(sSQL)) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            listadoUsuarios.add(rs.getString("usuario"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //maneja la excepción
        //manejo muy elemental
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //código para llenar la lista con la consulta a base de datos...
    return listadoUsuarios;
}
```

Comment: Vale que mejor explicación que esa no creo haber encontrado. Muchas gracias Luiggi, no se cómo voy a agradecerte toda tu ayuda. En una clase usé el try-with-resources pero, en otra clase se me ha olvidado y escribí la forma vieja por la costumbre. Gracias por hacerme darme cuenta de esto. Sobre el void, tienes razón, no lo había pensado, gracias por ese consejo. Aplicando esto lograré reducir muchas líneas. Como ya sabes mi experiencia es corta y aveces no puedo darme cuenta de posibles mejoras. Gracias nuevamente Luiggi.

Comment: Estamos para ayudarnos.

Comment: una última pregunta, para agregar al JComboBox los usuarios guardados en el List, se hace de esta manera?: for (String objeto : listadoUsuarios) { cboUsuarioExistente.addItem(objeto); }, nunca lo había hecho, fue lo primero que se me ocurrió.

Comment: @RobertGomez mira [aquí](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4747150/1065197) (en inglés pero el código se explica por sí solo)

Comment: Añadiría la información sobre como crear el array: `String[] listadoUsuarios = new String[numeroDeseado];`

Comment: @Error404 el problema es que para este caso no se sabe el valor de `numeroDeseado` a menos que se ejecute el query y se cuenten los resultados o que se ejecute un `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ...` solo para obtener ese valor, pero ambos siguen siendo "mucha cosa" para esto.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Sí, sólo me refería a indicarle al OP como se inicializaba para la próxima vez. Muy buena repuesta, BTW